# Dependency Injection - Have I refactored the code correctly?

Tags: java, oop, dependency-injection, refactoring

I'm attempting this question in preparation for a test. This is my best answer based on my understanding but I feel I may be missing something important. I think I have altered the responsibility of Navigator too much but I can't see a better way of doing it.

The question is:

```
public class Navigator
{
    private Route theRoute;

    public Navigator(UserInterface ui) {
        String destination = ui.getDestEntry().getText();
        theRoute = new Route(GPS.getLocation(), destination);
        theRoute.calculateRoute();
    }

    public void display() {
        MapView theMap = new MapView();
        theMap.plot(theRoute);
    }
}

public class GPS {
        public static String getLocation() { ... }
    }

“{ ... }” stands for an algorithm that we do not need to examine, for our purposes.
```

Refactor the Navigator and GPS classes to conform to the Dependency Injection pattern. Do not alter their basic responsibilities.

(a) Your refactored Navigator and GPS classes: (You will have more space on the
real test.)

(b) The injector code (just as a sequence of statements)

My answers:

(a)

```
public class Navigator {
   private Route theRoute;
   private MapView theMap;

   public Navigator (Route inRoute) {
      theRoute = inRoute;
      theRoute.calculateRoute();
   }

   public void display(MapView inMap) {
      theMap = inMap;
      theMap.plot(theRoute);
   }
}

public class GPS {
    public GPS(); //constructor

    public String getLocation(){...}
}
```

(b)

Injector code:

```
UserInterface ui = new UserInterface;
String destination = new String(ui.getDestEntry().getText());
GPS gps = new GPS;
Route theRoute = new Route (GPS.getLocation(), destination);
new Navigator(theRoute);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could be better.

```
public class Navigator {

  private final Route theRoute;
  private final MapView theMap;

  public Navigator(Route inRoute, MapView theMap) {
    theRoute = inRoute;
    this.theMap = theMap;
  }

  public void setup() {
    theRoute.calculateRoute();
  }

  public void display() {
    theMap.plot(theRoute);
  }

}
```

b) Your injector code is incomplete or wrong

Comment: Thanks, I'd forgotten to make the call to navigator in the injector code, is that what you mean by incomplete?

Comment: Hmm, yes :)

Navigator nav = new Navigator(theRoute); nav.display(map);

Comment: Injector code is only in two lines here: Route theRoute = new Route (GPS.getLocation(), destination);
new Navigator(theRoute);

Other code is not injector related

Answer (score 0):

The `Navigator` has dependency to  `GPS`, so you need to add property to the navigator

```
public class Navigator
{
    private GPS gps;
    private UserInterface ui;

    public Navigator(UserInterface ui, GPS gps) {
        this.ui = ui;
        this.gps = gps;
    }

    public void display() {
        String destination = ui.getDestEntry().getText();
        Route theRoute = new Route(gps.getLocation(), destination);
        theRoute.calculateRoute();
        MapView theMap = new MapView();
        theMap.plot(theRoute);
    }
}

public class GPS {
   public String getLocation() { ... }
}
```

Comment: Doesn't having the constuctor calls (Route theRoute = new Route(gps.getLocation(), destination) violate the dependency injection principles?

Comment: It depends on if it has dependency or not, in your question you state the dependency on GPS. The code is more clear if it has less dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

My c# refactored variant looks like:

```
public class ClientCode
{
    void DoNavigations(IDestinationEntry ui, IGPS gps)
    {
        String destination = ui.getDestEntry().getText();
        IRoute theRoute = new Route(gps.getLocation(), destination);
        INavigator nv = new Navigator(theRoute);
        nv.display();
    }
}

public class Navigator : INavigator
{
    private IRoute _theRoute;

    public Navigator(IRoute theRoute)
    {
        _theRoute = theRoute;
        _theRoute.calculateRoute();
    }

    public void display()
    {
        MapView theMap = new MapView();
        theMap.plot(_theRoute);
    }
}

public interface IGPS
{
    string getLocation();
}

public interface INavigator
{
    void display();
}

public interface IDestinationEntry
{
    DestinationEntry getDestEntry();
}

public interface IRoute
{
    void calculateRoute();
}
```